# how to get multiple users id from acf wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created a field with user type user with multiselect so when the admin add the post he will select multiple user so   how to get multiple user id  in custom post  type loop  here's the code i used

```
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'offers',
                    'orderby' => 'title',
                    'order' => 'ASC'
                );
                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );         
             if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

echo            $variable = get_field('select_user');
             endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: Have you checked if that field exists in the database? The code looks like it would work.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer for others.

Comment: submitted can you solve my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367209/how-to-pass-parameter-in-wordpress-plugin