# how to pass parameter in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to pass argument in function and print the output in wordpress plugin i was not able to pass parameter here's my code

```
global $postidd;
$postidd=$_REQUEST["postid"];
function getcontent($postidd)
{
   // do something with the args


if($postidd)
{

      $args12 = array(
                    'p'=>15,
                    'post_type' => 'offers',
                    'orderby' => 'title',
                    'order' => 'ASC'
                );
      $the_query12 = new WP_Query( $args12 );           
      if ( $the_query12->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query12->have_posts() ) : $the_query12->the_post(); 

     return   $postidd;

      endwhile;endif;     

         return   $postidd;

}
}
```

Comment: You need to explain a bit more the problem. Where are you calling this function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want any variable outside your function available to your function then use closures by using 'use' keyword like this:

```
$postidd=$_REQUEST["postid"];
function getcontent($somevariable) use ($postidd) {
....

or 
declare it global inside the function like this:
function getcontent($somevariable) {
global $postidd


but using global is considered a bad practice
```